# Set div's width equal to another div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to give my `.second_div` the width of `first_div`, but the problem is that the first div does not have a width value given in css and I need to find his width using jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class="first_div">First Div</div>
<div class="second_div">Second.width == First.width</div>
```

CSS:

```
.second_div,
.first_div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".second_div").css({'width':($(".first_div").width()+'px')});
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ekqecjb8/1/

Comment: you are missing jquery library https://jsfiddle.net/qnu7gzgm/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8f1vz5Ls/2/ - works fine(with jQuery library added)

Comment: Stupid mistake...Thank you!

Comment: what code should I add so that second_div will have width = 100% - first_div ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Missing jQuery library in your fiddle, there is no error in your code . Just include jQuery library in your code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".second_div").css({
    'width': ($(".first_div").width() + 'px')
  });
});
```

```css
.second_div,
.first_div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first_div">First Div</div>
<div class="second_div">Second.width == First.width</div>
```

Comment: what code should I add so that second_div will have width = 100% - first_div?

Comment: `$(window).width()-$(".first_div").width()`