# Set always width of one element to width of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I know how to get the width from one element and set the width of another element, when the page is being loaded (see [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721816/set-divs-width-equal-to-another-div)).

But if the side width is getting changed (for example if you resize the browser window), the width of the element won't change.

How can I "link" the width of one element to another sibling/element?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
function set_elements_width(_selector){
 var max_width = 0;
 $(_selector).each(function(){
    var el_width = $(this).width();
    if(max_width < el_width){
       max_width = el_width;
    }
 });
 $(_selector).css({'width': max_width});
}

function set_different_width(){
  /* this function for test only */
  $('label:eq(0)').css('width', 10);
  $('label:eq(1)').css('width', 20);
  $('label:eq(2)').css('width', 30);
  $('label:eq(3)').css('width', 25);
}



$(window).resize(function(){
    set_elements_width('label');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 set_elements_width('label');
});
```

```css
/* for test only */
label{
          border-style:solid;
          border-width:1px;
          display:inline-block;
          overflow:hidden;
          padding:2px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label style="width:10px;">111</label>
<label style="width:20px;">222</label>
<label style="width:30px;">222</label>
<label style="width:25px;">000</label>
<br/>
<input type="button"  value="set different widths" onclick="set_different_width();"/>
<input type="button"  value="set same width" onclick="set_elements_width('label');" />
```